# Custom autocompletetextview adapter not filtering and inputting weird strings

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I have made a custom adapter for a autocompletetextview, but it's not filtering on the text and inputting weird strings when you select a item. Like this string:

```
listadapters.LocatieRowItem@BSE433q4e30
```

I have made this adapter so the first item of the autocompletetextview could have a image and a different color then the rest.

Here is my custom adapter:

```
public class LocatieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LocatieRowItem> {

Context context;
private List<LocatieRowItem> items;

public LocatieAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<LocatieRowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LocatieRowItem rowItem = items.get(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.locatieitem, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(rowItem.getTitle().equals("huidige locatie")) {
        if (holder.imageView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#33B5E5"));
            holder.txtTitle.setPadding(40, 10, 5, 5);
        }
    } else {
        holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
        holder.txtTitle.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    }
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

    //convertView.setBackgroundColor(position % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.parseColor("#F8F8F8"));
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: You should set the text like `holder.txtTitle.setText(items.get(position).getTitle()`.

Comment: It diden't work when I select a item it still puts that weird string in the text field.

Comment: You try to implement methods like `@Override
 public int getCount() {
  return items.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return items.get(position);
 }
 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
 }`

Comment: The problem issen't by setText right? because that is setting the text of the textview in the item from the autocomplete(that is going fine), my problem is that when I select a item that weird string will be set in the textfield from the autocompletetextview.

Comment: In that case post the code of Itemclick .

Comment: O god I'm stupid I forgot to create a OnItemClickListerner I did this and it works:


`@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  LocatieRowItem item = (LocatieRowItem) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
  txtAutoVan.setText(item.getTitle());
 }`

Comment: Now to get the filtering working...